# When attempting to ssh into a server OSX continually prompts me for the password

Tags: macos, unix, ssh

I recently moved from pc to mac, essentially all of my keys keep getting the system asking me for a password, the normal pass for the file does not work, advice?

Edit: What the solution ended up being was creating a openssh key with puttygen which requires fully setting up a bunch of things, such as tools on xcode. Keys moved from Windows to Mac with passwords will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advice?

1.) explain what you mean by "the normal pass for the file does not work"

2.) look at the logfiles. Always look at the log files if you have an issue with a server

Most likely it is one of two aspects:

1.) you have not installed the keys beforehand (right place, right permissions etc)

2.) the server is not configured to accept keys

Comment: Another possibility is that the line endings in the key files need to be fixed.

Comment: @twalberg: true, actually general spoken: the keys may be invalid. And that might well be caused by MS-Windows-like linebreaks. You must use unix style linekbreaks. It is the difference between "\n" and "\r\n".

Comment: It was created on putty, so I am checking, they work on filezilla and cyberduck, without issue, but the terminal wants a password.

Comment: So... and what do the log files say?

Comment: Found an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475069/use-ppk-file-in-mac-terminal-to-connect-to-remote-connection-over-ssh